# How to update SwiftUI Binding variable in another CLASS

Tags: swiftui, state

I am a newbie to SwiftUI, and I have a simple question, how to update the @State content of a VIEW in another Class, a simulated Code is as follows

When I press the button, the fruits.price variable is not updated in the View. Is there something I'm missing, or is there something wrong I don't understand

```
class Fruits: ObservableObject {
    @Published var price = 1
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fruits = Fruits()

    var extenalClass = ExtenalClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(fruits.price))
                .padding()
            Button("Add-Me") {
//                fruits.price += 1
                extenalClass.fChangePrice()
                print (fruits.price)
            }
        }
    }
}


class ExtenalClass: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var fruits = Fruits()
    
    func fChangePrice() {
        fruits.price = 888
        print (fruits.price)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any `@State` in your example. You should probably not nest `ObservableObject`s either -- that's not really a supported paradigm in SwiftUI. Also, be aware that your `ExternalClass` would get re-created on every render of your `View`. It'd probably be a good idea to check out some SwiftUI tutorials (Apple's and Hacking With Swift's are excellent) and get familiar with some of the basics in SwiftUI.

Comment: The, um, "pragmatic" way to do that would be to create a shared instance of the Fruits object. As for your code, I'm afraid, ObservedObject is meant to work for Views and will not do do what you expect it to do in arbitrary classes. Besides, based on your code, the fruits variables in the view and in the seconds class would point to different objects and wouldn't do what you expect even if ObservedObject was more universal. Essentially, you create a separate object in each case.

Comment: Here's what I would do: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/a4a4dfad16a47b701576fb4d459f1198 Of course, ExternalClass in this example doesn't store anything so making it Observable and Observed serves no purpose but, perhaps, there will be something there in the future so I kept that part.

Comment: Actually, what I really need is... one of the variables inside a View... and I want to change that variable from another External Class (eg: message received from Bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

We don't use classes in SwiftUI for model types, we use structs. Any change to the struct is detected by SwiftUI as a change to the state, so body is called to get the new Views, e.g.

```
struct Fruit {
    var price = 1
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fruit = Fruit()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(fruit.price, format: .currency)
                .padding()
            Button("Add-Me") {
                fruit.price += 1
                print (fruit.price)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks malhal ... In fact, the Class I want has only one element. I tried to use "State" but failed, so I tried "ObservableObject" .. But the important thing is, I want to update the "price" variable from another ExternalClass (not in ContenView ) ... I use "Button" just for easy testing.

Since I'm just starting to learn Swift, maybe the question is a bit stupid ... :(

Comment: In that case you need to make a few things, a struct that holds a manager object and an object that holds an array of the structs that contain the price. That object is usually an environmentObject in SwiftUI. Take a look at PersistenceController in a new Xcode project with core data checked to get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks jnpdx, Baglan for the guidance .... I just found out my answer (probably not the right way), which is to put @Published and "My Function" together in the same CLASS...that is, Function is placed in the CLASS containing @Published...or, another way of saying , put @Published in the CLASS that contains "My Function"

```
class Fruits: ObservableObject {
    @Published var price = 1
    
//      Move (ExtenalClass) Function to here
        func fChangePrice() {
            price = 888
            print (price)
        }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fruits = Fruits()

//    var extenalClass = ExtenalClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(fruits.price))
                .padding()
            Button("Add-Me") {
//                fruits.price += 1
                fruits.fChangePrice()  // Modified
                print (fruits.price)
            }
        }
    }
}


//class ExtenalClass: ObservableObject {
//    @ObservedObject var fruits = Fruits()
    
//    func fChangePrice() {
//        fruits.price = 888
//        print (fruits.price)
//    }
//}
```